# How to Hide and show an Android Component on a single tap on screen inside Webview?

Tags: java, android, xml

In my Android project, I have designed one **.xml layout** where I have used one **Webview**. And inside that **webView** I have added some other android components like- **Linearlayout, Buttons, SeekBar, TextView**.

**Here's the code for my .xml layout-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeWebview"
    tools:context=".new_package.reader_version_2.reader_v2.ReaderV2Activity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="168dp"
            android:layout_y="223dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
    </WebView>


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#cdcdcd"
                android:thumbTint="#000000"
                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvProgress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:text="Brightness"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBackground"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="background"

                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFontSize"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="font"

                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="save"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the output of this layout-

[image]

****** **So, now, the problem is** *******

I want to make the **LinearLayout(at bottom of the screen)** hide on single tap on screen and it will not also not be visible while I am scrolling the screen. It will appear again when I do a single tap on screen again.

In short, I need a solution for that so that I can hide and show that layout inside webview by single tap.

I have tried following solutions but none of them worked for me-
[How to Hide and Show Buttons on Alternate Touch Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474384/how-to-hide-and-show-buttons-on-alternate-touch-events)

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the activity click events using this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the MotionEvent is on the view you are targeting for, you can apply your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this code as given below to hide status bar and component this will help you in hiding status bar and component

```
 public void setStatusbarTransparent(Activity activity) {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(0x00000000);


            // transparent
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
            window.addFlags(flags);
        }
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);

    }
```